# Way of usage <a4j:ajax> inside <h:commandLink>

Tags: jsf, richfaces

The first way:

```
<h:commandLink id="printSelectedReportsLink" value="${msg['page.dfeOper016form.button.printAll']}" target="_blank"  
             action="#{PDFReportsMBean.printSelectedScannedDoc}" 
             onclick="uncheckScannedDocsCheckboxes(); 
             {#{rich:element('printSelectedReportsLink')}.style.display='none';
             #{rich:element('printSelectedReportsText')}.style.display='inline';};" 
             style="#{PDFReportsMBean.selectedAnyDocs ? 'display: inline' : 'display: none'}">
```

The second way:

```
<h:commandLink id="printSelectedReportsLink" value="${msg['page.dfeOper016form.button.printAll']}" target="_blank"  
            action="#{PDFReportsMBean.printSelectedScannedDoc}" onclick="uncheckScannedDocsCheckboxes();" 
            style="#{PDFReportsMBean.selectedAnyDocs ? 'display: inline' : 'display: none'}">
        <a4j:ajax event="click" 
            oncomplete="{#{rich:element('printSelectedReportsLink')}.style.display='none';
            #{rich:element('printSelectedReportsText')}.style.display='inline';}" />
```

The first way works, `onclick` actions run also `action` method runs.
The second way does not work correctly, `onclick` actions run but method does not run, I checked this in the debugger...
What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

the default ajax event for action components  is event="action" your action method is not called bcos the action event is not queued since you have given event as click

solutions: use event="action" or remove it (it would work fine)